# How to fix error in "Copying template" when making project?

Tags: react-native

I'm generating a new project using `React-Native` in Command Prompt but I get an error when I use the following command:

```
react-native init Style
```

This is the result I get:

> √ Downloading template
>       × Copying template
>       error Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\rncli-init-template-srEvW0\node_modules\react-native\template.config'
>       error EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir 'D:\FUSI\React Native\Style'. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
>       Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir 'D:\FUSI\React Native\Style'
>           at Object.rmdirSync (fs.js:684:3)
>           at rmdirSync (D:\FUSI\React Native\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\remove\rimraf.js:276:13)
>           at Object.rimrafSync [as removeSync] (D:\FUSI\React Native\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\remove\rimraf.js:252:7)
>           at Object.initialize [as func] (D:\FUSI\React Native\node_modules\react-native\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\init\init.js:295:26)
>           at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: couldn't find template.config.js when creating a React Native project version 0.59.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63130867/error-couldnt-find-template-config-js-when-creating-a-react-native-project-ver)

Answer (score 4):

Mustafa AK had it right. What worked for me is adding the --npm flag at the end of the command.

I followed the tutorial exactly how it was laid out on the [React website](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) and was running into the same error. For whatever reason, if you have yarn and npm installed the command to create a new project will not work. So you have to add the --npm flag to get it to only use npm and this will work.

```
npx react-native init AwesomeProject --npm
```

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71725307/16114216) as well.

1. Be sure uninstall global react-native/cli as described react-native tutorials
2. Try to use `--npm` end of the `init` command if you have both yarn and npm.

```bash
npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript --npm
```

If you have both yarn and npm installed on your machine, the React Native CLI will always try to use yarn. So even if you use the npx utility, only react-native executable will be installed using npm and the rest of the work will be delegated to yarn. You can force usage of npm adding `--npm` flag to the command.

Answer (score 0):

**This Same error comes with me. But I solved by following ways...**

1. First, uninstall the node from your system and download the latest version of node and install it.

   2.after installation of the latest version of node you need to write the command in your command prompt

   npm install -g react-native-cli
2. Now go to your project directory

   cd your-react-native-project directory
3. now create your react-native project

   react-native init your-project-name.