# Error: couldn't find template.config.js when creating a React Native project version 0.59.9

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

When I try to create a react native project version 0.59.9 I get the following error

> error Error: Couldn't find the "/var/folders/zc/h93bvpb573q24_5ynvgkn1wc0000gn/T/rncli-init-template-0YT6FZ/node_modules/react-native/template.config.js file inside "react-native" template. Please make sure the template is valid.

How can I resolve this issue?

The command I used is `npx react-native init Awesome --version 0.59.9`

How can I resolve this issue, and what could be the cause of it?

Here's a screenshot of the terminal as well

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use a template from another version

```
npx react-native init Awesome --version 0.59.9 --template=react-native@0.60.0-rc.1
```

Answer (score 17):

1. Be sure uninstall global react-native/cli as described [react-native tutorials](https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript)
2. Try to use `--npm` end of init command if you had yarn and npm both.

   npx react-native init MyApp --npm

[Note](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/init.md#creating-custom-template): If you have both yarn and npm installed on your machine, React Native CLI will always try to use yarn, so even if you use npx utility, only react-native executable will be installed using npm and the rest of the work will be delegated to yarn. You can force usage of npm adding --npm flag to the command.

Comment: --npm worked for me

Comment: --npm works for me on Mac M1